# Python commacode adding and

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment where we have to write a comma code as described from the book

Say you have a list value like this:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
```

Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return `apples, bananas, tofu, and cats`. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

We are to write it with these details:

- In your program, create four lists as follows:

  ```
  animalList1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'tiger', 'lion', 'camel']
  animalList2 = ['elephant', 'alligator']
  animalList3 = ['horse']
  animalList4 = []
  ```
- When you run your program, pass each list to the `commaCode()` function and then print out the result as shown in the Example Output.

I'm really stuck and don't know if I'm heading in the right direction. This is my code so far:

```
animalList1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'tiger', 'lion', 'camel']
animalList2 = ['elephant', 'alligator']
animalList3 = ['horse']
animalList4 = []
spam = [animalList1, animalList2, animalList3, animalList4]

def commacode(list):
    spam[-1] = 'and ' + str(spam-[1])

    for i in range(len(spam)-1):
        spam[i] = str(spam[i]) + ','
        stringList = ''

        for i in range(len(spam)):
            stringList = stringList + str(spam[i])
            print(stringList)

print(commacode(spam))
```

Comment: You got those particular test cases because you have to handle lists with no items, one item, two items, and three or more items differently. After you've taken care of that, look up the `join` method of strings.

Comment: For starters, your `commacode()` function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code also works. Firstly, you have 4 lists in the spam list. So you need to iterate over it. That is what the last 2 lines do. Each time a list is passed as a parameter to the `commacode` function. According to your expectations, the length of the list is identified to check if the length is 1. If the length is 1 it means there is one item. So that is printed out. If the length is 0 nothing is done. If the length is not zero then `items` in the list are iterated and concatenated to the string with a comma. Every item is checked on whether it is the last item. If it is the last item, the string will contain and as well.

```
from varname import nameof

animalList1 = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'tiger', 'lion', 'camel']
animalList2 = ['elephant', 'alligator']
animalList3 = ['horse']
animalList4 = []
spam = [animalList1, animalList2, animalList3, animalList4]
name_of_list = [nameof(animalList1), nameof(animalList2), nameof(animalList3), nameof(animalList4)]

string = ""
counter = 0

def commacode(list, list_name):
    global string

    length = len(list)
    if length == 1:
        string = list[0]
    elif length != 0:
        for item in list:
            if list.index(item) == length-1:
                string = string + "and " + str(item) 
            else:
                string = string + str(item) + ", "
    else:
        string = "-"
    print(f"{list_name}: {string}")
    string = ""

for list in spam:
    commacode(list, name_of_list[counter])
    counter += 1
```

The output that I got:

```
animalList1: dog, cat, bird, tiger, lion, and camel
animalList2: elephant, and alligator
animalList3: horse
animalList4: -
```

Comment: thank you so much! Is there a way to get to print like this : animalList1 - dog, cat, bird, tiger, lion, and camel
animalList2 - elephant and alligator
animalList3 - horse
animalList4 -

Comment: Yes, of course. I have edited my answer to print the name of the list as well. `Variable` names are for coders to understand. We cannot retrieve the name of the list just as `str` from the `spam` list. So, I have imported a python package called `varname` to do this. `nameof()` will return the name of the list as a string value. All the strings of list names are added to the `name_of_list`. Check that thread > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871665/how-to-find-the-name-of-a-list-in-a-list-of-lists-instead-of-its-value/53871836

Comment: thank you for that, your comment and link was very helpful. But I'm not sure if it's a python issue but I get an error for  **varname**.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/commaCode.py", line 4, in <module>
    from varname import nameof
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'varname'

Comment: Oh. The module `varname` is not pre-installed with python. It is a third party library. https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname You need to `pip install varname`

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(mylist):
    if len(mylist) == 0:
        return ""
    elif len(mylist) == 1:
        return mylist[0]
    else:
        return ", ".join(mylist[:-1]) + " and " + mylist[-1]
```

you need to add exception cases.
using `.join` makes things easy.

learn about join here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/

learn about list indexing and slicing here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-basics-of-indexing-and-slicing-python-lists-2d12c90a94cf

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not allowed to use `join` here. You must first take care of special cases for empty lists and singletons, then add all elements with another special processing for the last one.

Here is a possible Python code:

```
def commacode(lst):
    # an empty list gives a blank string
    if len(lst) == 0:
        cr =  ''
    # a single element list returns its element
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        cr = lst[0]
    # else all elements are joined with  ' ,' except last with ', and'
    else:
        cr = lst[0]
        # list has at least 2 elements so list[1:-1] is defined
        # (it is at least empty for just 2 elements)
        for elt in lst[1:-1]:
            cr += ', ' + elt
        # special processing for the last element
        cr += ', and ' + lst[-1]
    return cr

for lst in spam:
    print(commacode(lst))
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
dog, cat, bird, tiger, lion, and camel
elephant, and alligator
horse

>>>
```

(I have added a prompt display make the last empty line visible)

---

If you can use `join`, the `else` part could be:

```
    else:
        # list has at least 2 elements so list[1:-1] is defined
        # (it is at least empty for just 2 elements)
        cr = ', '.join(lst[:-1]
        # special processing for the last element
        cr += ', and ' + lst[-1]
```